# Reuse of JPA `Specification` on joiuned entities

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Say that I have written a small *library* of reusable JPA specifications this way, as more of syntactic sugar

```java
public static Specification<Person> lastNameEquas(String lastName) {
    return (r,q,cb)->cb.equals(r.get(Person_.lastName),lastName);
}
```

Imagine a lot more predicates and I use them such as:

```
Specification<Person> s = where(firstNameEquals("John"))
                          .and(lastNameEquals("Smith"))
                          .and(ageGreaterThan(18));
```

I am facing the problem of reusing defined `Specification<T>` for `T` entity also in context where `T` is a **joined entity** of `U`

Given that class `Person` is `@OneToMany`-joined to `Pet`, and that I have specifications both for `Person` and `Pet`, I want to reuse helper methods both for `Person` and `Pet` in the same construction of the specification

```java
@Entity
public class Person{

    ......

}

@Entity
public class Pet{

    private String name;
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne
    Person owner

}
```

I want a `Specification<Pet>` that can be combined with reusable `Specification<Person>` instances

```java
Specification<Pet> spec = where(PetSpecs.petNameEqual("Lucky"))
                          .and(PetSpecs.petAgeGreaterThan(1))
                          .and(PetSpecs.owner(
                              personNameEquals("John")
                              .and(personAgeGreaterThan(18))
                          ))

select from Pet p where
p.name = 'Lucky' and p.age > 1 and p.owner.name = 'John' and p.owner.age > 18;
```

**What I have tried so far**

I want to write a method `public static Specification<Pet> owner(Specification<Person>)` that takes in input any `Specification-of-Person` and applies it to the joined attribute, resulting in a `Specification-of-Pet` that can feed the query

More generically, I could try to write

```java
    public static <T, U> Specification<T> joinedSpecification(@NonNull SingularAttribute<T, U> joinAttribute, JoinType joinType, Specification<U> joinSpecification) {
        if (joinSpecification == null) return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> null;
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<T, U> join = root.join(joinAttribute, joinType);
            return joinSpecification.toPredicate(join, query, criteriaBuilder);
        };
    }
```

The idea is that the Specification is a function that returns a predicate, so my predicate will recursively translate input specifications into more predicates, applied to the joined entity.

Now here is my problem. JPA defines `Specification<T>` as a lambda interface

```java
    Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder);
```

Note that `Root<X>` extends `From<X,X>` extends `Path<X>`, and `Join<T,U>` extends `Path<T,U>`.

The above code does not compile, because `root.join(...)` returns a `Join`, which **is** a `Path` (to get entity attribute) but is not a `Root`.

My question is: is it possible in JPA to reuse specifications to reapply in joined paths?

Answer (score 0):

That seems not to be a big deal to define your own interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Specification<X> extends Serializable {

    Predicate toPredicate(From<?, ? extends X> from, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb);


    default Specification<X> not() {
        return (from, cq, cb) -> cb.not(toPredicate(from, cq, cb));
    }

    default Specification<X> and(@Nullable Specification<? super X> other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return this;
        }
        return (path, cq, cb) -> cb.and(toPredicate(path, cq, cb), other.toPredicate(path, cq, cb));
    }

    default Specification<X> or(@Nullable Specification<? super X> other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return this;
        }
        return (path, cq, cb) -> cb.or(toPredicate(path, cq, cb), other.toPredicate(path, cq, cb));
    }

    default org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification<X> asSpring() {
        return this::toPredicate;
    }

}
```

However we have found that more convenient to reuse criteria predicates rather than spring specifications (at least the most of our developers prefer this option), smth. like:

```java
@Entity
public class Pet {

    private String name;
    
    private int age;

    public static Predicate hasName(From<?, ? extends Pet> from, CriteriaBuilder cb, String name) {
        return cb.equal(from.get(Pet_.name), cb.literal(name));
    }

    @ManyToOne
    Person owner;

}
```